# PM2 spams shells/terminal on start

Tags: node.js, pm2

So I'm using [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to manage my discord bots from a web interface and there is a button that starts all the bots.

**What Is the problem?**
Every time the function is run(or the button is clicked), a lot of shells spam open and close instantly on my screen.

**What does the function do?**
The function first gets all the discord bot directories from the main directory, then loops through them to find a `package.json` in each directory, using the main entry file from package.json to start the app.

The function:

```js
getDirectories(`./${process.env.SECRET_PATH}`, function (Data) {
    Data.forEach(Folder => {
        if (Folder.toLowerCase() != "logs") {
            if (!fs.existsSync(`./${process.env.SECRET_PATH}/${Folder}/node_modules`)) {
                fs.mkdir(`./${process.env.SECRET_PATH}/${Folder}/node_modules`, function () {
                    Terminal(`cd ./${process.env.SECRET_PATH}/${Folder} && npm install`).then(data => {

                    }).catch(err => {

                    })
                })
            }
            PackageFile = `./${process.env.SECRET_PATH}/${Folder}/package.json`;
            if (fs.existsSync(PackageFile)) {
                fs.readFile(PackageFile, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                    if (err) { console.error(err); }
                    Package = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(Package)
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        pm2.start({
                            name: Folder,
                            detached: true,
                            script: `./${process.env.SECRET_PATH}/${Folder}/${Package.main}`,
                            out_file: `./${process.env.SECRET_PATH}/logs/${Folder}.strout.log`,
                            error_file: `./CanorusNecked/logs/${Folder}.strerr.log`,
                        }, function (err, apps) {
                            if (err) { console.log(err) };
                        })
                    }, 250);
                })
            }
        }
    });
})
```

The opening shells:
[image]

Comment: I see that you're using a loop on each directory, check the `Data` at the beginning see if there's anything that should not be there. Currently you check if the folder is not the `logs` it will spawn a terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the help but that's not the terminal that opens, the shell is opened by pm2 not the terminal promise, If I comment out the terminal promise function it still happens.

Comment: Hmm, what about when you comment out the pm2.start process?

Comment: The pm2.start is the entire problem, that's the thing which is opening the shells in the first place. but it should open only one shell for each folder and I have 2 folders, so 2 shells total but it spam open and closes them.

Comment: It is still inside the loop, for each directory except logs, another thing that might cause this is the script that you're trying to run

Comment: I cant restart all apps/bots without the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240960/discussion-between-jub0t-and-areg).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the error by adding these values in the first parameter of the `pm2.start()` function.

```json
{
    detached: true,
    max_restarts: 5,
    min_uptime: 5000,
    watch_delay: 5000,
    autorestart: false,
    restart_delay: 1000,
    exp_backoff_restart_delay: 100,
}
```